# How to tell C++ shared Python module to use available cv2.so?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I'm writing a small C++ shared library which use OpenCV. I want to build it as cross-platform but there are cv2.so in Python modules. My question is that does my library use the cv2.so python module or system wide OpenCV shared lib? If not, how I can tell my library to use the cv2.so python module when I compile my library as a python module?

Comment: I suspect that a path to the answer is figuring out how to use (interface with) `numpy` from your module code. that's a more common use-case and the mechanism should apply to OpenCV as well... not just because OpenCV's python module also uses numpy, but because the same DLL/.so magic has to happen.